# Detect key override in python dictionary initialization

Tags: python

I have a large dictionary and I'd like to prevent a situation where a key can be *accidentally* overwritten. For example, this is valid python and doesn't raise an error, but I'd prefer to detect such a condition. I understand this is expected in python `dict()`, so I'm looking for ways to detect such issues:

```
In [6]: b = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'three': 6}

In [7]: b
Out[7]: {'one': 1, 'three': 6, 'two': 2}
```

Ideally I'd like the first value of `three` to be kept as the true value. I have looked at immutable dicts using `MappingProxyType`, but that only partially helps here. It still doesn't help with overwritten keys (at initialization, it correctly detects overwriting a key *post* declaration).

Comment: This would need to process the source code to detect such mistakes in a dict literal (or to modify Python itself). Module "ast" may help.

Comment: Indeed; a way to work around this problem would be to write the dictionary assignment in a text file, read and process the content of the text file, then use `ast.literal_eval` on the parsed text to create the dict.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. why would you do it?

Comment: I could put the values in a json and read off of it, and check for existence of the key. But I have complex expressions as values that introduce a different problem (evaluating string expressions), that I don't really want to deal with.